# Check If Post Was Published More Than 6 Months Ago Using get_the_date

Tags: php, single, date-time

Inside my `content-single` template, I have a conditional check that displays text based on how old the post is. The idea is to inform visitors that they might be reading "old" news.

Problem is; the `6+ months old` text is displayed on posts that are only days old, and I do not understand why.

**This is the code I am using:**

```
<?php
    
    if ( strtotime( get_the_date() ) < strtotime( '-1 year' ) ) { ?>

        <span class="old-post"> 6+ months old </span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
        
        <?php 
    } 

?>
```

This is the format I am using in WP admin for date and time:

```
l \t\h\e jS \of F @ H:i
```

Please help me understand how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your date format is not a standard format that `strtotime()` understands. Instead just use `get_the_date()` with the format set to `'U'`, which returns the timestamp, and compare that to `strtotime( '-1 year' )`:

```
if ( get_the_date( 'U' ) < strtotime( '-1 year' ) ) {

}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. And a huge big thanks for explaining.

Answer (score -1):

By using below code, you can check if Post Was published more than 6 Months ago using get_the_date.

place below code inside content-single template, It inform visitors that they are reading "old" news which is plublished 6+ months old.

```
# get last 6 month date from current date
$last_sixth_month_date = strtotime("-6 month"); 

# publish date
$post_poblish_date = strtotime( get_the_date() );

# get difference from two dates
$year1 = date('Y', $last_sixth_month_date);
$year2 = date('Y', $post_poblish_date);
$month1 = date('m', $last_sixth_month_date);
$month2 = date('m', $post_poblish_date);
$month_diffrence = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);

if($month_diffrence < 0 )
{
    # check difference between date is 6 or more than 6
    if(abs($month_diffrence) >= 6 )
    {
        echo  '<span class="old-post"> 6+ months old </span>&nbsp;/&nbsp';
    }
}
```

Comment: I did check and it is working fine. please let me know what's wrong with this code. so i can improve answer.

Comment: Wasn't me, but you are using the same `strtotime( get_the_date() )` which wasn't working for OP because of some configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Rup. I did check at my end and i got result as expected. Thanks for explanation 